# What is the best way to refactor a long string line in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-style-guide

I have a line of code like this

```
"#{envelope_quantity} - envelope #{Budget::util_name(envelope_size)} #{Budget::util_name(envelope_paper)} #{Budget::util_name(envelope_color)} #{Budget::util_name(envelope_grammage)} #{Budget::util_name(envelope_model)} #{Budget::util_name(envelope_print)}"
```

too long, it's bad to read, and that's why RuboCop is warning me with it's [Metrics::LineLength](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.47.1/RuboCop/Cop/Metrics/LineLength).

I would like to refactor it to not be a long line.

I know a lot of ways to do that, but I wonder which one would be the expected for the ruby style experts.

that static method util_name is needed to prevent nil when I need an empty string if it's nil.

```
def self.util_name(value)
  return '' if value.nil?
  value.name
end
```

Comment: Absent any context, it's difficult to give advice here. How I would approach this depends a lot on the objects in question and how they relate. What is the `self` object for this code? Why is it calling `Budget::util_name` for everything? Is this a standalone naming method or part of a larger piece of logic?

Comment: hey @AdamLassek, thank you for this. I edit my question to explain the util method, your other questions I don't get it really, or if I have I would have to explain a lot of this app

Comment: this piece of code is for a pdf report, if it's help, for contexting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breaking up long strings on multiple lines in Ruby without stripping newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522414/breaking-up-long-strings-on-multiple-lines-in-ruby-without-stripping-newlines)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this

```
str = "#{envelope_quantity} - envelope #{Budget::util_name(envelope_size)} "\
      "#{Budget::util_name(envelope_paper)} #{Budget::util_name(envelope_color)} "\
      "#{Budget::util_name(envelope_grammage)} #{Budget::util_name(envelope_model)} "\
      "#{Budget::util_name(envelope_print)}"
```

this way you will be able to confine the string within max line length and also its slightly more readable than using `join`

Comment: A new line for every Budget might be even more readable, depending on your preference

Comment: accepted since it's the way ruby-style-guide uses for long string https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-trailing-backslash

Comment: Nice use of the little-known trick of combining multiple strings. Although given the extra info added to the question, you can remove `Budget::util_name` completely and it will do the same thing.

Comment: No I can't. Explained why below your answer

Answer (score 7):

One thing you might try is to not use string interpolation, instead construct the string using concatenation and `join`:

```
"#{envelope_quantity} - envelope " + 
[Budget::util_name(envelope_size), 
 Budget::util_name(envelope_paper),
 Budget::util_name(envelope_color),
 Budget::util_name(envelope_grammage),
 Budget::util_name(envelope_model),
 Budget::util_name(envelope_print)].join(' ')
```

Even more concisely, you could use `map`:

```
"#{envelope_quantity} - envelope " + 
[envelope_size, 
 envelope_paper,
 envelope_color,
 envelope_grammage,
 envelope_model,
 envelope_print].map{|x| Budget::util_name(x)}.join(' ')
```

This might be made more concise by defining an array with all of the envelope properties in the right order and applying `map` to that:

```
envelope_properties=[envelope_size, 
                     envelope_paper,
                     envelope_color,
                     envelope_grammage,
                     envelope_model,
                     envelope_print]

"#{envelope_quantity} - envelope " + 
envelope_properties.map{|x| Budget::util_name(x)}.join(' ')
```

Of course, it would help if you happened to have another use for the `envelope_properties` array.

Comment: It's a really good one for me since I have to call util_name() method lot of times. But accordingly to ruby-style-guide "Prefer string interpolation and string formatting instead of string concatenation" https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#string-interpolation

Comment: Given the additional context, it's clear that `Budget::util_name` doesn't need to exist at all, and bringing `Enumerable` into this just adds needless complexity, IMO.

Comment: Nice solution, especially #2.

Comment: Seems like the `map` could actually be `map{ |x| x || "" }`, or it could be replaced with `compact` to remove the nils.

Comment: AdamLassek and @DavidAldridge that would be nice to remove that method if it was possible, unfortunately it's not possible explained in my comment for Adam's answer #comment-76030950

Comment: @RamonMarques is correct, I missed an important bit about the sample -- however my assessment here still stands. I've updated mine to account for the method call.

Answer (score 1):

> that static method util_name is needed to prevent nil when I need an empty string if it's nil.

```
def self.util_name(value)
  return '' if value.nil?
  value.name
end
```

---

Okay, given that bit of context you can remove the `Budget::util_name` method entirely because it isn't doing anything useful. There are two ways of conditionally calling a method on an object that might be `nil`, one provided by the framework and one by the language.

If you are using Ruby 2.2 or earlier, use the [try method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try).

```
value.try(:name)
```

if you are using Ruby 2.3 or above, you can use the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/)

```
value&.name
```

In either case, you don't need to specifically test for `nil` because it will be automatically coerced into an empty string when interpolated.

```
"#{envelope_quantity&.name} - envelope #{envelope_size&.name} #{envelope_paper&.name} #{envelope_color&.name} #{envelope_grammage&.name} #{envelope_model&.name} #{envelope_print&.name}"
```

That's much more reasonable, still probably a bit too long. You could use string templates:

```
"%{quantity} - envelope %{size} %{paper} %{color} %{grammage} %{model} %{print}" % {
  quantity: envelope_quantity&.name,
  size:     envelope_size&.name,
  paper:    envelope_paper&.name,
  color:    envelope_color&.name,
  grammage: envelope_grammage&.name,
  model:    envelope_model&.name,
  print:    envelope_print&.name
}
```

But I want to focus on something I noticed about this code sample. Every single method begins with `envelope` which probably means that [these methods are telling you they should be a separate object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bZh5LMaSmE). If you extract this data into a [value object](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/#value-objects), then the natural location for this helper method becomes obvious...

```
class Envelope < Struct.new(:quantity, :size, :paper, :color, :grammage, :model, :print)
  def to_s
    "#{quantity&.name} - envelope #{size&.name} #{paper&.name} #{color&.name} #{grammage&.name} #{model&.name} #{print&.name}"
  end
end
```

Undoubtedly the real code would be more complicated than that, just food for thought.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on my since-deleted answer. What was I thinking?

Comment: @AdamLassek thank you for your new and nice answer. Let me clarify something here. actually the util static method can't be removed because it's not just a "print blank method". I verify if a class 'not an attribute' is nil, then I print the 'name' attribute, that this time can be nil and the interpolation will call to_s automatically. Edit your answer if you agree with me, otherwise let me know what I'm not getting here.

Comment: Your code wouldn't work because you are never calling .name property in any of them, see?

Comment: I believe that you thought those envelope_size, _paper _color and so on were attributes because of its names, I know they are bad. Unfortunately that code is from a legacy app that I'm giving maintenance...

Comment: @RamonMarques you're right, I missed the call to `.name` in there. Still unnecessary, but I'll update to reflect that behavior.

Comment: @AdamLassek nice, I didn't know those methods, I'm going to start to use ^^ thanks.