# What's the difference between these six Ruby string syntaxes, are they concatenation, interpolation or maybe something else

Tags: ruby, string, string-concatenation, string-interpolation

I was trying to write a single string across multiple lines since it was too long and I arrived at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337510/ruby-can-i-write-multi-line-string-with-no-concatenation) that I think looks best but I couldn't find anything about it in the [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html)

```
    my_original = 'what I originally had ' +
                  'across multiple lines'       
    # executes to:  "what I originally had across multiple lines"

    new_style = 'new format to '\
                'span multiple lines'
    # executes to: "new format to span multiple lines\n"
```

However I saw of lot of ways this could be done and I was wondering whether they  uses concatenation or interpolation and [all I could find was this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076579/string-concatenation-vs-interpolation-in-ruby) In this case performance is not particularly important in this case but having the knowledge of what goes on under the covers cant hurt. So was wondering the differences between these.

```
        my_original = 'what I originally had ' +
                     'across multiple lines' 
        # executes to: "what I originally had across multiple lines"

        s_one = 'I assume this is a more ' 
        s_two = 'verbose version of the '
        s_three = 'first example.'
        my_string = s_one + s_two + s_three       
        # executes to: "I assume this is a more verbose version of the first example."

        my_first_solution = 'that breaks whenever' 
        my_first_solution << 'ruby 3.0 might be released'
        # executes to: 

        style_i_used = 'which can span multiple '\
                       'lines without having '\
                       'extra white space' 
        # executes to: "which can span multiple lines without having extra white space"

        another_string = <<-HEREDOC
when you don't mind
really wonky indentation 
        or having extra spaces.
        HEREDOC
        # executes to:"when you don't mind \nreally wonky indentation \n        or having extra spaces\n        and new lines. \n"
        # "Is this just a one line string with no special characters?# executes to:

        another_string = <<~HEREDOC
        I assume this is the same as 
        the non squiggly version with 
        stripping between lines.
        HEREDOC
        # executes to: "I assume this is the same as \nthe non squiggly version with \nstripping between lines.\n"

       #Edit
       another_one =
       "I did not originally include; however,
       this one also adds a bunch of extra 
       white space and new lines."
       # executes to:"I did not originally include; however,\n       this one also adds a bunch of extra \n       white space and new lines."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `NoMethodError`

```
style_i_used = 'a format to' /
               'span multiple lines'
```

`/` is a method call which Strings don't have. `\` on the other hand "escapes" the newline so it's treated as one string.

These won't give an error, but are **bad**:

```
my_original = 'what I originally had' +
              'across multiple lines' 

s_one = 'I assume this is the same as ' 
s_two = 'the first example with the '
s_three = 'code being more verbose'
my_string = s_one + s_two + s_three       

my_first_solution = 'that breaks whenever' 
my_first_solution << 'ruby 3.0 might be released'
```

`+` and `<<` are method calls. I don't think the Ruby parser is smart enough to see that these can all be compile-time strings so these strings are actually being constructed during **run-time** with object allocation and everything. That is entirely unnecessary.

The other kinds have different usage/results, so you use whichever is appropriate.

```
str = "a"\
      "b"  # result is "ab"

str = "a\
b"         # also "ab"

str = "a
b"         # result is "a\nb"

str = <<END
  '"a'"
  '"b'"
END
# result is "  '\"a'\"\n  '\"b'\""

str = <<~END
  '"a'"
  '"b'"
END
# result is "'\"a'\"\n'\"b'\""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
another_one =
"what I originally had
across multiple lines"
```